# how to parse data from dynamic json retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I want to parse data from below given JSON into an android spinner. POJO class not working for this. I am using retrofit and GSON android studio

```
"complaint_list": {
  "1":"light not working",
  "2":"fan not working",
  "3":"refrigerator not working ",
  "4":"lock not working"
}
```

by parsing data I will populate this data into a spinner

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: TBH nothing, looking for way i am quite new to this thing

Comment: i tried but unable to find correct one, if you have one please share

Comment: Please share actual response you getting.

Comment: {
 "complaint_list": {
  "1": "light not working",
  "2": "fan not working",
  "3": "asdasd",
  "4": "dvij"
 },
 "nature_of_complaint_list": {
  "1": "low priority",
  "2": "high priority",
  "3": "asdasd"
 }
}

Comment: Please follow my answer,please update it's working or not..

Answer (score 1):

**If Your Json like this**

```
    { 
   "complaint_list":{ 
      "1":"light not working",
      "2":"fan not working",
      "3":"refrigerator not working ",
      "4":"lock not working"
   }
}
```

You need To parse like this

```
JSONObject jsonMain = new JSONObject("YOUR_JSON");
JSONObject json= json.getJSONObject("complaint_list");
ArrayList complaintList= new ArrayList<String>();
Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String key = iter.next();
    try {
        String value = json.get(key);
        //json.getString(value) --> here you can get your jsonObject value.  
        complaintList.add(json.getString(value));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // Something went wrong!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a list of string from your json
2. Populate your spinner with ArrayAdapter

   ```
   ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);  
   spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
   mySpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
   ```